# Is there a way to make the psutil output consistent between runs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sed, psutil

I'm trying to get some data out of `psutil`. Specifically I want to get the `memory_percentage` and `name` data in this order.
Here is the code:

```
def getListProcessMem():
    for proc in psutil.process_iter(attrs=None, ad_value=None):
        procInfo = proc.as_dict(attrs=['memory_percent', 'name']) 
        procInfo = proc.as_dict(attrs=['name', 'cpu_percent'])
        theOneProcessList.append(procInfo)
    return(theOneProcessList)

getListProcessMem()
output = theOneProcessList
with open('zawarudo.txt', 'w') as f:
    for processes in theOneProcessList:
        f.write("%s\n" % processes)
```

The problem is, sometimes the output order is wrong and it ends up writing the `name` of the process first then the `mem_prec`.

`sed` then handles the cutting of the data but since sometimes the order is wrong, the final output file is garbled.

Is there a way to keep it consistent? mem first then name

Answer (score 0):

if you want it sorted, just use `dict(sorted(processes.items()))` instead of `processes`

iteration on dict is done in insertion order, sample test code below

```
>>> p1 = { 'name': 'dummy', 'mem':33}
>>> p2 = {'mem':33, 'name':'dummy'}

>>> print ("%s\n" % p1)
{'name': 'dummy', 'mem': 33}
>>> print ("%s\n" % p2)
{'mem': 33, 'name': 'dummy'}

>>> print ("%s\n" % dict(sorted(p1.items())))
{'mem': 33, 'name': 'dummy'}
>>> print ("%s\n" % dict(sorted(p2.items())))
{'mem': 33, 'name': 'dummy'}
```